# Why does AtomQ[y] define y?

Tags: programming

Mathematica Version 11.2 desktop / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

```
(* Assume y is undefined. *)

(* ?y and ??y leave y undefined. *)

?y

Information::notfound: Symbol y not found.

??y

Information::notfound: Symbol y not found.

(* AtomQ[y] has a side effect of defining y. *)

In[3]:= AtomQ[y]

Out[3]= True

In[5]:= ??y

Global`y
```

Why does AtomQ[y] define y?

Is this "By Design" i.e. a carefully thought out deliberate feature?

One would think that if y is not defined, AtomQ[y] would output this as an error.

Why else would one be using AtomQ[y] unless they thought y was already defined.

It seems like a dangerous side effect which makes debugging a nightmare.

Is there a property of the Kernel to enable or disable functions like AtomQ from defining symbols?

In general, which built-in functions leave symbols undefined and which do not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The creation and removal of symbols in contexts is described in the tutorial http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicObjects.html. I'm not sure "define" is the right term to describe what happens. For instance `Definition[y]` returns `Null`, if you haven't given `y` any definitions or attributes, even though the name `"y"` is added to the ``"Global`"`` context.

Comment: Invoking `foo[bar]` puts both of `foo` and `bar` into the name space, in whatever is the current `Context`. But it does not mean either one has become "defined' in the sense of having `DownValues` or the like associated to them.

Comment: It doesn't *define* it. It *creates* the symbol. Simply saying `y` creates the symbol `y`.

Comment: I think linked topic answers your doubts and provides much more background. Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `AtomQ`. Constructing an expression containing a symbol automatically gives it a definition. It doesn't even need to be evaluated. It acquires a presence in some context (usually `Global`), but not a value.

"Definition" isn't a formal *Mathematica* concept. Is a symbol that exists in some context "defined"? Yes, in the sense implied by this question, but no in the sense of having a value.

Comment: @Kuba As the comments above imply, "definition" isn't a formal *Mathematica* concept. Is a symbol that exists in some context "defined"? Yes, in the OP's sense, but no in the sense of having a value.

Comment: Thanks for the edit